# Why are the Automorphisms $\text{Aut}(T_2)$ of the regular, infinite, binary rooted tree the **length-preserving** permutations?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, trees, automorphism-group

Why are the [Automorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigorchuk_group#Definition) $\text{Aut}(T_2)$ of the regular, infinite, binary rooted tree the **length-preserving** permutations?

This suggests to me that only swaps of vertices (and all their children) which are at the same number of edges from the root as each other, are permissible.

But it seems to me that we could take any pair of vertices on this tree and swap them (along with all their children) and the graph would remain isomorphic to the original.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: The graphs would be isomorphic, but the map wouldn't be adjacence-preserving, I think.

Comment: They are not. The article states it is those which preserve the initial segment relation.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Yes, that would be right.  Adjacence-preservation is important for automorphism is it?

Comment: By definition, an automorphism of a rooted tree fixes the root. Therefore, the subset of vertices connected to the root by one edge, which is the subset of vertices at distance 1 from the root, is mapped to itself by the automorphism. Continuing by induction, the subset of vertices connected to the root by a path of $n$ edges, which is the subset of vertices at distance $n$ from the root, is mapped to itself by the automorphism.

Comment: @DaveP I quote "**length-preserving** permutations $σ$ of ${\displaystyle \Sigma ^{*}}$ that also respect the initial segment relation"

Comment: Perhaps one other thing you are missing: an automorphism of a tree (root preserving or not) is *automatically* length preserving, because the edge-path between any two vertices $v,w$ is unique and hence is mapped to the unique edge path between the image vertices $v',w'$, and the lengths of those two edge-paths are equal.

Comment: @LeeMosher yes that's the bit I'm not getting, thanks. Still struggling to visualise it.  It's possible I've misunderstood "length-preserving". If we imagine the dyadic rationals modulo $1$ in a tree with $\frac{1}{2}$ at the top, then $\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}$ next and $\frac{1}{8},\frac{3}{8},\frac{5}{8},\frac{7}{8}$ next and so on.  Does "length-preserving" mean only adjacent elements can be exchanged - i.e. $\frac{1}{4}$ is the only element which can be exchanged for $\frac{3}{4}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll turn my comments into an answer.

In any tree, one can assign lengths to the edges, so that all edges have length equal to $1$. Next, for any two vertices $v,w$ in the tree, there is a unique "edge-path" in the tree having endpoints $v,w$, and the length of that path is equal to the number of edges along it (just add up all the $1$'s, one for each edge in that path).

One can prove that any automorphism $f$ of a tree preserves lengths by a simple induction argument. The basis step of the induction goes like this: if $v,w$ are connected by an edge path of length $1$, then they are connected by a single edge, so $f(v)$ and $f(w)$ are connected by a single edge, so $f(v)$ and $f(w)$ are connected by an edge path of length $1$.

In the example of your comment, the dyadic tree with root $1/2$, we have the following relations:

- the vertices that are connected to $1/2$ by an edge path of length 1 (a single edge) are indeed $1/4$ and $3/4$,
- the additional vertices that are connected to $1/4$ by an edge path of length $1$ are $1/8$ and $3/8$;
- the additional vertices that are connected to $3/4$ by an edge path of length $1$ are $5/8$ and $7/8$;
- so, the vertices that are connected to $1/2$ by an edge path of length $2$ are $1/8$, $3/8$, $5/8$, and $7/8$.
- the edge path in this tree that connects the vertex $1/8$ to the vertex $3/4$ has length $3$:
  $$\frac{1}{8} --- \frac{1}{4} --- \frac{1}{2} --- \frac{3}{4}
  $$

Any automorphism of this rooted tree will fix the root $1/2$, and it will permute the two vertices $1/4$ and $3/4$, and it will permute the four vertices $1/8$, $3/8$, $5/8$, $7/8$. But those permutations are not independent of each other, because the automorphism must preserve length. So, for example, if the permutation interchanges the two vertices $1/4$ and $3/4$, and if the permutation fixes the vertex $1/8$, then that permutation is *not* an automorphism of the tree because it does *not* preserve lengths: the length of the edge-path between $1/8$ and $1/4$ and equals $1$ whereas the length of the edge-path between $1/8$ and $3/4$ equals $3$, and $1 \ne 3$.

**Edited:** As opposed to that negative example, here is a positive example to address your latest comment. One can define an automorphism that which does not "leave any vertex where it was" except for the root vertex. Specifically, the automorphism will take $1/4 \mapsto 3/4$, and it will take $1/8 \mapsto 5/8$, and $3/8 \mapsto 7/8$, and then one can continue defining this automorphism inductively for higher and higher powers of $2$ in the denominator. And in actuality there is a simple numerical formula for this automorphism: for any dyadic rational number $r$ we have 
$$f(r) = \begin{cases}
r & \quad\text{if $r = \frac{1}{2}$} \\
r + \frac{1}{2} &\quad\text{if $r < \frac{1}{2}$} \\
r - \frac{1}{2} &\quad\text{if $r > \frac{1}{2}$}
\end{cases}
$$
No vertex will "stay where it was", in other words no vertex (but the root) will be fixed by this automorphism.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I hadn't correctly understood the nature of a tree automorphism. It appears at least in the case of this infinite, binary rooted tree, we can think of these automorphisms as equivalent to leaving the vertices where they were, and simply exchanging pairs of labels $T_L$ for $T_R$ where $T_l,T_R$ share an upward-vertex. Is that correct?

Comment: I think perhaps your latest comment is still not quite right, and I've edited my answer to include an example which does not seem to match what you wrote.

Comment: Thanks Lee, that's crystal clear. I did understand correctly but I probably didn't explain well what I meant by exchanging $T_L$ and $T_R$.  But in the example you give $T_L=-\frac{1}{4}$ and $T_L=+\frac{1}{4}$ so the automorphism swaps these for all children below a given point in the graph, moving them by $\frac{1}{2}$.